# Duda con Quill Editor

Tags: laravel, blade, quill

estoy usando el panel Vuexy en laravel y estoy agregando un apartado para controlar Terminos y Condiciones...  debo ponerlos en el mismo formulario, pero en diferentes columnas.

Al momento de guardar y demás no tengo ningún problema...

Estoy usando este panel:

https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-bootstrap-laravel-admin-template/demo-4/form/quill-editor

```
<section class="full-editor" id="form1" name="form1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="card-title">Detalles del Service</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">
            Ingresar la descripción de los 
            <code>problemas</code> encontrados. esto será enviado al <code>Cliente</code>. en conjunto con el detalle de la solución, los componentes a emplear y sus precios.
          </p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div id="full-wrapper">
                <div id="full-container">
                  <div class="editor">
                    Problema:
                    <p></p>
                    @php
                    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($detailservice->solution);
                    @endphp
                    <br/>
                    Solución:
                    <p></p>
                    @php
                    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($detailservice->solution);
                    @endphp
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-12" align="center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" id="save">Enviar</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancelar</button>
              </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

esto funciona a la perfección, pero debajo copio y pego el mismo y pongo en id form2 y name form2 por ejemplo... y el primero funciona y el 2ndo se ve simplemente el texto del formulario y no el editor en si...  si al 1ero le cambio

```
class="full-editor"
```

por

```
class="full-editor 2"
```

por ejemplo.. el 1ero se ve solo el texto y el segundo se ve bien.

este es el ejemplo de "editar" pero en el de crear tengo el mismo problema.

como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Y el javascript? Según el ejemplo del link tienes que poner `var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: '#toolbar'
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ mala mía el error era que estaba llamando a un js de demo en lugar de llamar al script del quill y agregando el javascript personalizado! mil gracias!

Comment: Vale. No conozco la librería, pero abrí el link que pusiste y me pareció que habría que iniciar cada uno con ese objeto pasándole el id de la etiqueta

Answer (score 0):

Solucion **FORM QUILL EDITOR:**

Link CSS:

```
<!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/css/vendor.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<!-- CSS Front Template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/css/theme.min.css?v=1.0">
```

Link JS:

```
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
<script src="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
<!-- JS Front -->
<script src="https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v4.2/html/assets/js/theme.min.js"></script>
```

En mi html:

```
<form id="form-perfil" name="form-perfil" method="POST">
  <!-- Form Group -->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label input-label">BIO</label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <!-- Quill -->
      <div class="quill-custom">
        <div
          class="js-quill"
          style="min-height: 15rem;"
          data-hs-quill-options='{
                       "placeholder": "Type your message...",
                        "modules": {
                          "toolbar": [
                            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "link", "image", "blockquote", "code", {"list": "bullet"}]
                          ]
                        }
                       }'
        >
          Creative mind at Htmlstream
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Quill -->
      <textarea name="text_quill" style="display: none;" id="text_quill"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Form Group -->

  <button type="submit" class="mt-3 float-right btn btn-primary">Enviar formulario</button>
  <!-- End Form Group -->
</form>
```

En mi JS:

```
// INITIALIZATION OF QUILLJS EDITOR
// =======================================================
var quill = $.HSCore.components.HSQuill.init('.js-quill');

// =======================================================
$("#form-perfil").on("submit", function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); //No se activará la acción predeterminada del evento

  $("#text_quill").val($(".ql-editor").html());

  var formData = new FormData($("#form-perfil")[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/pago_administrador.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (datos) {  },             
  });
});
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).